# Least squares solution problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares

> Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}
> 2 & 0 & 2 \\
> 1 & 1 & 2 \\
> 1 & 1 & 2 \\
> 2 & 0 & 2 
> \end{pmatrix}$. Determine the least squares solution for $Ax = e_4.$

The least squares solution can be found from $A^TAx = A^Te_4$. This is problematic since $A^TAx = \begin{pmatrix}10&2&12\\ 2&2&4\\ 12&4&16\end{pmatrix}x = \begin{pmatrix}2\\ 0\\ 2\end{pmatrix}$, but $x$ cannot be solved from here since I cannot multiply the RHS by $A^{T^{-1}}$... What can I do here?

Comment: The vector $(0,0,0,1)^T$

Comment: You have to invert the $3 \times 3$ matrix $A^TA$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I have that $\det \begin{pmatrix}10&2&12\\ 2&2&4\\ 12&4&16\end{pmatrix} = 0$ so it's not invertible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the matrix

$$B=A^TA=\begin{pmatrix}10&2&12\\ 2&2&4\\ 12&4&16\end{pmatrix}$$ is not invertible, the solution of the least square problem is a linear subspace of dimension greater or equal than $1$. Indeed the kernel of $B$ is a linear line.

You can solve the system
$$Bx = \begin{pmatrix}2\\ 0\\ 2\end{pmatrix}$$ to find this linear line.

Comment: Here I have that $B^{-1}Bx = x  = B^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}2\\ 0\\ 2\end{pmatrix}$, but again $B$ is not invertible so I'm not this system is solvable?

Comment: Indeed, you can't solve by tacking the inverse. However, you can find multiple solutions by writing $B\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\ x_3\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}2\\ 0\\ 2\end{pmatrix}$.